# Facebook Login stopped working because of long redirect url

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, horizon

I have horizon 1.1.3 app running with google and facebook login.
Yesterday my facebook login stopped working. (Google login is working).
When trying to login I get "oauth provider error"
After some investigation, I see this on my server:

```
wget https://my_site.com/horizon/facebook?code=...&state=...%2BwagQ%3D
[1] 1736

The name is too long, 337 chars total.
Trying to shorten...
New name is facebook?code=...
--2016-09-11 05:35:05-- https://my_site.com/horizon/facebook?code=...
Resolving my_site.com (my_site.com)... 1.1.1.1
Connecting to my_site.com (my_site.com)|1.1.1.1|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: /?horizon_error=session%20expired [following]
The name is too long, 337 chars total.
Trying to shorten...
New name is facebook?code=...
--2016-09-11 05:35:06-- https://my_site.com/?horizon_error=session%20expired
Reusing existing connection to my_site.com:443.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: 'facebook?code=...'

facebook?code=... [ <=> ] 306 --.-KB/s in 0s

2016-09-11 05:35:06 (30.8 MB/s) - 'facebook?code=...' saved [306]
```

Looks like the "code" parameter makes the url too long, then the server tries to shorten it and cuts the hash which makes the request invalid.
Did someone encountered this error?